# Magento - how to check if logged client bought the current product

Tags: magento, client, product

hope someone can help me.

In one of my magento stores i wish display an instruction video only if the logged client bought the product he is seeing at the moment.

Conditions to see the video are:

> Client should be logged in
>
> Must have purchased that product in the past or in last month

Thats what i have so far... ( in product view, p.e. )

```
<?php if(Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->isLoggedIn()): ?>VIDEO CODE...<?php else: ?>WARNING MESSAGE<?php endif; ?>
```

What i "think" i need?!

> load the items purchased by specific client ID
>
> check if logged client ID bought the current product ID

Thanks in advance and regards

Answer (score 0):

Another thought would be to create a customer attribute, something along the lines of bought_product_xyz. Default to 0, once they purchase the product, set it to 1 and then run a check against that.